# 3rd party nic shows "Linkdown"

Tags: drivers, server, network-manager

I installed a QXG-10G1T qnap ethernet card into my Ubuntu server about 2 weeks ago and have been slamming my head into the wall trying to figure out what isnt working.  for some context on the connection, the server right now is connected through 2 different routes to the internet.
connection 1 uses the built-in 1g NIC directly to the ISP router at 192.168.1.0/24
the 2nd (target) is through the new 10G NIC into my lab network at 192.168.3.64/26
im only keeping the 1G connection as failover and testing

I went through the readme to install it as thoroughly as possible. I got some amdgpu errors when running through the install files and (just to eliminate ANY POSSIBLE ISSUES) spent a day and a half chasing down the files to clear the errors, but otherwise I got the drivers installed and the card recognized as "enp39s0" with my on-board nic set as "enp34s0":

```
enp34s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2603:6080:7d03:7962:2ef0:5dff:fea2:10f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2603:6080:7d03:7962:0:2785:3604:4e63  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::2ef0:5dff:fea2:10f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2c:f0:5d:a2:10:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 349261  bytes 462730680 (462.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 407  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 192797  bytes 24479304 (24.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp39s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.126  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 192.168.3.127
        ether 24:5e:be:57:f5:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

​

as you can see "enp39s0" isnt passing any traffic. and when i check my routes, the NIC shows "linkdown." When i assign it an IP address and connect it to the same system as the onboard NIC i can ping the ip address which i assume is the server sort of routing traffic through 34 to 39 and responding back. I tried checking dmesg and found some weird text:

```
[ 0.992153] r8169 0000:22:00.0 enp34s0: renamed from eth0

[ 1.727005] atlantic 0000:27:00.0 enp39s0: renamed from eth0

[ 14.993139] r8169 0000:22:00.0 enp34s0: Link is Down

[ 17.917521] r8169 0000:22:00.0 enp34s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx

[ 17.917540] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp34s0: link becomes ready

[ 407.754551] atlantic 0000:27:00.0 enp39s0: renamed from eth0

[ 4327.795974] r8169 0000:22:00.0 enp34s0: Link is Down

[ 4409.452381] r8169 0000:22:00.0 enp34s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

so it looks like "enp39s0" was renamed from "eth0" but that should be the first port and used by "enp34s0" instead right? are both these NICs trying to pipe through the same connection? am i misreading that entirely? im fully expecting this is something stupid simple thats keeping my new NIC in a linkdown state but like i said ive been staring at this for about 2 weeks and I have run out of ideas.

I tried getting ahold of QNAP and they told me they cant help, that i need to call marvell, and they could not be bothered to get back to me at all so im turning here for help.  I'm running linux server 20.10 with debian 5.8.0.  I can provide modinfo for the atlantic driver if needed but I feel like this might be more of an "improper configuration" issue

here's the printout of the netplan file:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp39s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.3.126/26]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 208.67.220.220, 8.8.8.8]
      gateway4: 192.168.3.65
    enp34s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.6/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 208.67.220.220, 8.8.8.8]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2
```

and routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp34s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp34s0
192.168.3.64    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 enp39s0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: i could write it on every single page in my notes and forget it each time i start diving into the weeds on problems:

*********ALWAYS CHECK LAYER 1*********

the problem was a bad hand-made cable.  the cable has worked for the last 4 years no problem but now for some reason one of the pins took a dump on me in transition to the new setup.  everything is up and works fine now.
again, dont forget the basic stuff when troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

If the link isn't up, how can you expect the NIC to route traffic?
At first check why no link can be established. Status of LEDs at NIC and link partner, which modes are advertised from both sides, etc.

Comment: did you pay attention to the post?
I know its not going to pass traffic if the link isnt up.  my question is why the link wouldnt be up at this point in my troubleshooting
both the card and the switch are running auto negotiation and the lights are all off